# Make some TextArea rows optional/invisible based on previous row input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, user-interface

Make some rows in textarea optional/invisble based on previous row input. Initially, all textarea rows are mandatory, as we are using “required”.

I have the JSON payload for texarea. Now, based on the value of fileFormat row, I want to make delimiter and processFiles row optional or the shouldn’t be visible . For Example,

For the very first time, we type fileFormat as “CSV”, current scenario is fine. Then before submitting the form, changed fileFormat to “PARQUET”,  need to make delimiter and processFiles optional or invisible. If we again type fileFormat as “CSV”, then delimiter and processFiles option should be visible and mandatory.

```
<textarea class="form-control required" id="payload" rows="14"  placeholder = "Enter JSON payload here">

{
    “Metadata”:{
        “delimiter”: “”
    },
    “fileFormat”: “”
        “processFiles”:””
}
</textarea>
```

I tried bewlow code, but having some difficulties with it. Any other suggestion will be helpful.

```
    let payloadContent = document.getElementById('payload');

        const newPay = payload.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
            if (payloadContent.value.includes("parquet")) {

         let reg = new RegExp('"delimiter": "",', 'gi');
         if (payloadContent.innerHTML.match(reg)) {
              const newPayload = JSON.parse(payloadContent.value);
              if(newPayload.fileFormat === 'parquet') {
                payloadContent.value = payloadContent.innerHTML.replace(reg, '');
                }


              }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself so far, and if so, can you post it here, please?

Comment: @user7290573 I added the code I tried. It's not working out exactly the way it should. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle which should do what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/db9pwu1y/

A few things to note:

1. My example uses jQuery as your post has a `jquery` tag.
2. Your code contains invalid JSON: `“fileFormat”: “”` - these should be double quotes, i.e. `"`.
3. If you're working with JSON, you don't need/shouldn't be trying to get values using `RegExp`; this is what `JSON.parse()` is for.

Interactive example:

```js
$(function() {
 const payloadTextarea = $("#payload");
 const formatSelect    = $("#file-format");

 // Listen for changes on the <select> element
 formatSelect.on("change", function() {
  const payload    = {};
  const fileFormat = $(this).find(":selected").val();

  payload["fileFormat"] = fileFormat;

  if (fileFormat === "CSV") {
   payload["Metadata"]     = {"delimiter": ""};
   payload["processFiles"] = "";
  }

  // "stringify" the payload object and set as <textarea> value
  payloadTextarea.val(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 4));
 })

 // Trigger the "change" event manually so the event listener handles the default <select> value
 formatSelect.trigger("change");
})
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
textarea {
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="file-format">
 <option value="CSV" checked>CSV</option>
 <option value="PARQUET">PARQUET</option>
</select>
<textarea class="form-control required" id="payload" rows="14"  placeholder="Enter JSON payload here"></textarea>
```

Comment: @user72905723 thanks for your reply. The above code works fine. Is it possible to add more rows than just delimiter and processFile for the solution you gave? For example, ``` "Metadata":{
       "delimiter": "",
     "file-name": "",
     "file-regex”: ""
    },
    "fileFormat": "",
    "processFiles":"",
    "appName":""
} ```

Comment: Then just assign whatever extra values you want to the `payload` variable - `payload["row_1"] = "val_1";` etc.

Comment: @user72905723  just wondering if it's possible without select option in textarea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, definitely possible - that was just one way of passing the `fileFormat` value into the logic.

Comment: @user72905723 As I am newbie to the UI, it will be great if you can please help me out with it? Thanks!

Comment: How were you getting the `fileFormat` value originally? A separate input element?

Comment: using document.getElementById and addEventListener.

Comment: By the looks of your original code, you're using the same `<textarea>` to capture user input *and* output the `payload` JSON; it's very poor usability if you type in "CSV" and then suddenly the element's contents changes to JSON. Use a separate element - a `<select>` like in my example or an `<input type="radio" />`.